# aiohttp ws_response coroutine

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to send multiple messages to websocket server asynchronously.
Code I'm using (shortened for clarity):

```
class Bitfinex(object):

    def __init__(self, session):
        self.ws_conn = session.ws_connect(self.WS_URL)

    async def subscribe(self):
        tasks = [
            self.ws_conn.send_json(self.SUB_MESG.update({'prec': self.PREC_MAP[pair], 'pair': pair}))
            for pair in self.PAIRS
        ]
        await asyncio.wait(tasks)
        res = self.ws_conn.receive()
        self.logger.debug('Subscribe result: {}'.format(res.data))
```

driver script:

```
from bitfinex import Bitfinex


async def main():

    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    try:
        # Duplicate objects just for testing purposes
        collectors = [
            Bitfinex(session),
            Bitfinex(session)
        ]

        # Subscribe to orderbook channels.
        subscriptions = [
            col.subscribe()
            for col in collectors
        ]
        await asyncio.wait(subscriptions)

    finally:
        session.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Correct initialization of ws_conn object should be according to the aiohttp documentation `async with session.ws_connect(ws_url) as ws_conn:`. That statement returns `ws_conn` as `ClientWebSocketResponse` object. I tried to initialize `ws_conn` without context manager and got `_WSRequestContextManager` type instead which doesn't have `send_json()` method. How can I get proper object without context manager and without direct `ClientWebSocketResponse` initialization?

Answer (score 0):

[ws_connect](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientSession.ws_connect) is a coroutine, so you need to await for it's result

```
self.ws_conn = await session.ws_connect(self.WS_URL)
```

but you can't use await expression outside the coroutines, so you need to move it from `__init__` method